# File attributes dataset

Tags: cloud, storage, google-bigquery

I need a dataset for my machine learning experiments. I try to extract from Google Bigquery but I could not understand how to do it.

what I need is a dataset (of storage file logs) consisting of files attributes such as ( file name , create time, owner , permissions ....etc) . 
is there any similar data from NFS storage or does anybody know how to extract it from Google Bigquery

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a dataset like this, but try requesting in some open data forums like [/r/datasets](http://www.reddit.com/r/datasets), or StackOverflow's sibling site [opendata.stackexchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Once you find it, you could load it into BigQuery for easy analysis. And if it's open data you could also make it public, and share the new location on the same forums.